# How many H.264 videos can Nvidia's NVDEC decode at once?

Tags: video, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, hardware-acceleration

I need to know (or be able to calculate/measure) how many H.264 videos of a given resolution, bit rate etc. can be decoded on the GPU at once, whilst maintaining a frame rate of at least 30 for all.

I am trying to work out what is the throttling factor which limits and reduces performance when multiple videos are being decoded at once, AND the max. number of videos each card is capable of.

I am also keen to know what I can do to increase the number of videos, be that through software or hardware (including which hardware I buy).

If you know of some relevant resources you could point me towards, that would be much appreciated.

I believe decoding is done on the NVDEC chip, rather than by CUDA now-a-days?

I am already familiar with the following resources: NVDEC_DA-06209-001_v08.pdf, NVidia video SDK, Video Encode and Decode GPU Support Matrix

A bit of background for you: I am working on a video player which is designed to play multiple (e.g. 30) videos at once. I would like to figure out what the upper limit of simultaneous decoding is before performance is noticeably impacted to the point that frame rate falls beyond 30fps.

I am also looking to play H.265, and VP9 videos with this player, but I excluded them from the title and main question as I suspect most people are more familiar with H.264.

Many thanks for taking the time to read this! I look forward to your answers.

Comment: Have you tried to test this on your NVDEC hardware? That's the easiest way to get an answer. Chances of anyone just "knowing" the number (which probably depends on the hardware) are pretty slim.

Comment: I do agree @dirkt, I am more looking for some pointers towards which components of the GPU might affect it. I believe most cards of a given architecture generation have an almost identical NVDEC chip(s), so with this in mind and keeping all other variables constant (HDD, Memory, CPU...) the results should be similar. Unless of course it relies on other components of the GPU. This is all the kind of info I am after. How can I compare card X to Y, and how can I therefore calculate an approximate upper limit per card.